# How to fix the next thread to be more correct? Using Pthread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm investigating the use of PThread.

The main process opens the camera and gets a matrix. Then calls the thread that running job in robot and I want it to be parallel. Basically it works and runs. But still feel unprofessional- because of the `bool`.

In the code below, this is an example (with `fprintf`).

I'd love to know how I can fix it without harm parallelism.

In the next code I do not show the call to the robot or camera opening.

There is a feeling that a mutex is needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <unistd.h> /// for sleep



bool inThread = false;
void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

int main()
{
    char mkey = 0;
    pthread_t thread1;
    char *message1 = "Thread 1";
    int  iret1;
    cv::Mat bgr_image = imread("image.bmp",cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
       while(mkey!=27){
        if(!inThread){
            inThread = true;
            iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
           }
        printf("In Main");
        imshow("mat", bgr_image);
        mkey = cv:: waitKey(5);
    }
   return 0; 
}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
    char *message;
    message = (char *) ptr;
    printf("%s \n", message);
    sleep(2);
    inThread = false;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The code works great and does not fall, but it seems unprofessional. Is there a chance that when you update the flag, it will check what is in the flag and fall?

Comment: This `cv::Mat` smells like C++.

Comment: "*There is a feeling that a mutex is needed.*" the feeling is correct.

Comment: @alk thanks about yore comments, I use c thread because i need to move to thread  struct from the main proces. about your next comment thanks also that mean that I need mutex instead of flag. you can explain me way?

Comment: `main()` is no valid C++, implicit int return value only existed in C, but was dropped in C99 as well...

Comment: @ Aconcagua thank for your comment. the example of code is not the real one. I just want to understand about the thread. but I will fix that.

Comment: The flag is OK. It's just that when being read/written concurrently this read/write access to the flag needs to be protected, which typically is done by using a mutex.

Comment: @alk great this is what I try to ask. thank you very much

Comment: OT: regarding: `bool inThread = false;`   This could be: `int inThread = 0;`  where the code could use 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`

Comment: OT: The posted code uses a mix of statements from both C and C++.   Suggest doing yourself a big favor and stick with all statements from one language.

Comment: @OT I would love to understand why I should remain with only one language. Sometimes things are easier to do in C than in C ++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inThread` is concurrently read/written so its access shall be protected.

Using a mutex this can for example be done like follows.

- Define a global mutex and initialise it:

  ```
  pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  ```
- Include `errno` to be able to do convenient error checking/logging for the `pthread_*()` calls:

  ```
  #include <errno.h>
  ```
- Change this

  ```
    if(!inThread){
      inThread = true;
      iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
    }
  ```

  to become

  ```
    errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    if (errno) {
      perror("pthread_mutex_lock() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (!inThread) {
      inThread = true;

      errno = pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
      if (errno) {
        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      ...
    }
    else {
      errno = pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
      if (errno) {
        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  ```
- And change this

  ```
    inThread = false;
  ```

  to become

  ```
    errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    if (errno) {
      perror("pthread_mutex_lock() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    inThread = false;

    errno = pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    if (errno) {
      perror("pthread_mutex_unlock() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  ```

Comment: regarding: `errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&m);`  This overwrites the system variable `errno`  User code should only test that value, not write to it.

Comment: @user3629249: There is absolutely *no* reason to *not* write to `errno`. The idea with the code above is that as the `pthread_*()` functions do *not* set `errno` to do exactly this in order to be able to use `perror()` for logging.